# How to make check multiple checkboxes when different radio button is clicked in asp net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want the different checkbox to be checked when the different radio button is clicked.

I tried the following code but when I run the webform page, the checked box only checked as expected when I click on the first radio button and then it stops working.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
            $("#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                $("#<%= CheckBox7.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox8.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox9.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox10.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox18.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox11.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox19.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox20.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox12.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox13.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
            });

            $("#<%= CheckBox2.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                $("#<%= CheckBox7.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox8.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox9.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox10.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox18.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox11.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox19.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox20.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox12.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox13.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
            });

            $("#<%= CheckBox3.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                $("#<%= CheckBox7.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox8.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox9.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox10.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox18.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox11.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox19.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
                $("#<%= CheckBox20.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox12.ClientID%>").attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%= CheckBox13.ClientID%>").attr('checked', false);
            });

        });
```

What would be the reason that cause the issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the checked attribute in the .aspx page itself, rather than using jquery to set the defaults?

Comment: @LawrenceZahner Do you mean to do this from server side?

Comment: Yes, using the [CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event